# 'Unexpected token, expected ")"' on catch block when adding Typescript to ReactJS project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, try-catch

I'm converting a ReactJS project to use Typescript. When I compile the project, on the catch block in `try/catch` statements,

```
...
} catch (e: any) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

I get the following error

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ")" (243:15)

  241 |         ...
  242 |       });
> 243 |     } catch (e: any) {
      |               ^
  244 |       console.log(e);
  245 |     }
  246 |   };
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

This project was created using `create-react-app`.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. The only option I have right now, is to remove the `(e:any)`, and have a generic error message.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. This is the first time I'm converting a ReactJS project to use Typescript.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put type annotation in `catch` block as you don't know what error will be thrown.

Workaround is to use `instanceof` to check which error you got

```js
catch (e) {
  if(e instanceof RangeError) {
    // e is now RangeError
  } else if (e instanceof TypeError) {
    // e is now TypeError 
  } else {
    // anything else
  } 
}
```

Source: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-typing-catch-clauses/